# Assigning issues to yourself on GitHub

Tags: git, github

In lots of [GitHub](https://github.com/) project wikis is stated that you should assign issues to yourself to begin collaborating on that project, but I don't see any way of doing that. Is it because I don't have permissions? I also forked a repo and, upon creation of an issue, I don't see anything that allows me to link to or reference a main repository issue... What's then the procedure for assigning issues to yourself on GitHub?

Much appreciated for any help.

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally the workflow to fix a bug/issue on github project is:

1. fork a repo
2. create a new branch
3. fix the bug in the new branch
4. create a pull request from your branch to upstream project, when you can reference the original issue

I would suggest you follow [github fork-a-repo tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo) and looking for more detail in https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests

BTW, you can always reference to a github issue in your commit message/review comments/pull request in this format: User/Project#Num, e.g. mojombo/github-flavored-markdown#1 will point to https://github.com/mojombo/github-flavored-markdown/issues/1

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The "BTW" paragraph was all I needed to know. I honestly would really like to know why you assumed I did not know about the normal workflow of bug/issue fixing on GitHub or about forking and pulling requests. Wasn't my question clear enough?

Comment: @lalalalalala I think I misunderstood what you means by " assign issues to yourself "

Comment: Ok, thanks. Then I take that my question is not clear enough because it has already been down voted and surely its not because any lack of  research effort because this is not an obvious issue and I really found nothing on the web on how to assign issues to myself!

Comment: @lalalalalala I don't think a non-perfect title deserved a down vote, so I gave your question an up vote. Cheer up :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to self-assign an issue. What I did was simply click the "Issues" tab on the main page of my repo:

[image: (Image 1 - Issues tab)]

After that, I just created a new Issue:

[image: (Image 2 - New issue button)]

And when I clicked on the assignees section and selected myself:

[image: (Image 3 - Assignees section)]

The example I gave you was of a repository I own. But I tried it in a private repository that somebody invited me and it worked as well.

Maybe the problem is that you are not invited to that specific repository you are trying to self assign? I tried this in repository I am not invited to and GitHub didn't give me permission to change the assignees section.

[image: (Image 4 - Assignees section blocked)]